# Django redirect to another view not working: no reverse match

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a view that I just want to redirect to another view for test purposes. And I want to call it by it's view name like show in the docs:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

but when I do like this

```
def randomQuestion(request):
    random_question = Question.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    return redirect('testDirect')
```

it gives me the error "no reverse match":
[image]

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
def testDirect(request):
    return HttpResponse("redirected to correct pagge")


def randomQuestion(request):
    random_question = Question.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    return redirect("/polls/testDirect")
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [

    #ex: /polls
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # ex: /polls/5/results/  #the <int:question_id>
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),

    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),

    #ex:/polls/random/
    path('random/', views.randomQuestion, name='randomQuestion'),

    #ex: /polls/testDirect/
    path('testDirect', views.testDirect, name='testDirect'),
]
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: When the docs say "name of a view" they don't mean the name of the function in `views.py`, they are referring to the name parameter passed to paths in `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`. Share your urls?

Comment: @IainShelvington - I added the URLs, it does match what I have, that's confusing me

Comment: Try `redirect("polls:testDirect")`

Comment: @IainShelvington dang, thanks Iain that worked. I just finished the part of the tutorial that had me add app_name for the {% url %} templating. Forgot I had to now reference the name via app_name in front. Thank you man!